# R: save a regex match to a new variable while removing the regex match from the existing variable using `str_extract()`

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to save a regex match to a new variable and remove the regex match from the existing variable using one function.

So in the following example, I want to remove "Speaker. " from sentence and save it to `new_variable` while also removing "Speaker. " from `sentence`.

I tried to accomplish this with `str_extract()`. I am able to match the desired word, but the word is not removed from `sentence`. (This may not be what `str_extract()` was designed to do, but then what is the difference between `str_extract()` and `str_match()`??)

```
library(stringr)

sentence <- "Speaker. I am not sure why this does not work."

for(line in sentence) {
  new_variable <- str_extract(line, "^[[:alpha:]]+\\. ") 
}
```

I know I can use `str_replace()` to remove the regex match from sentence, but I would prefer to do this with one function if possible.

```
library(stringr)

sentence <- "Speaker. I am not sure why this does not work."

for(line in sentence) {
  new_variable <- str_extract(line, "^[[:alpha:]]+\\. ")
  sentence <- str_replace(sentence, test, "")
}
```

Comment: Can you give sample data for this and expected result? Will there always be a period there? Is there anything else you want to split? etc.

Comment: try `str_remove` or `str_remove_all`

Comment: Please provide mor examples and the expected output. You may do well with `str_split`, hard to tell. `sentence %>%  str_split("(?<=[[:alpha:]])\\. ")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::separate_wider_regex`

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(sentence = "Speaker. I am not sure why this does not work.")

separate_wider_regex(df, sentence, c(new_variable = "^[[:alpha:]]+\\. ", sentence = ".*"))
```

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  new_variable sentence                             
  <chr>        <chr>                                
1 "Speaker. "  I am not sure why this does not work.
```